# How to find internal DNS records that are pointing to an IP

Tags: domain-name-system, windows-server-2012-r2, nslookup

Ive got a number of internal DNS records that have been setup to point to a test web server.  Its been a while since they were setup and I want to see whats pointing to a particular server.

So I have multiple internal DNS records like this:

```
test-app1.deptname.company.com  >>>> routes to ip1
test-app2.deptname.company.com  >>>> routes to ip1
test-app3.deptname.company.com  >>>> routes to ip1
```

I want to find all the urls mapped to ip1.  Can I do that with nslookup?  Its a Windows DNS

Comment: Just examine your DNS server configuration. It will be trivial to see what hostname are pointing to ip1.

Comment: Yes, thanks.  I got my network admin to look this up.

Answer (score 0):

Examine your DNS server configuration to find all records point to your desired IP address.